# 403 Forbidden Error on Mac OS X Localhost

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server

I set up Web Sharing in System Preferences on Mac OS X 10.6 and clicked the link it gave me there. Unfortuantely, Apache gave me this 403 error:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /~myusername/index.html on this
>   server.

Access log displays: `10.0.1.2 - - [30/Jun/2010:16:25:15 -0700] "GET /~myusername/ HTTP/1.1" 403 210`

Error log displays: `[Wed Jun 30 16:26:09 2010] [error] [client 10.0.1.2] client denied by server configuration: /Users/myusername/Sites/`

Curiously enough, accessing http://localhost works fine. It's just with two of the user folders that I've having trouble with, the other user folder, which is newer than my system upgrade, is working fine.

I've had this working on my machine in Leopard before, so I chmodded everything in `~/Sites` to 755, which didn't do any good. Any suggestions? I presume I've done something to my machine that's caused this, since I can't imagine Apple messing up on something like this.

I did set up PEAR with [these instructions](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/), but I have no idea if that could be the cause of it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but exactly what URL are you going to?  I ask because the URL "/~myusername/index.html" is an odd one -- it should either be "~myusername/index.html", or it should be "http://localhost/~myusername/index.html", or something similar.  Simply starting from / and then adding ~myusername smells funny.

In addition to (or instead of) answering that, you can go into Console.app (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app) and find the apache2 access_log and error_log.  Pull that up, perhaps clear the display, and then re-try your URL to see what the error log tells you.

Comment: @khedron: The URL is http://localhost/~myusername/index.html, but the error displays the /~myusername/index.html part

Comment: OK, just checking.  What does the apache log say in the console (console.app)?

Comment: @khedron: I posted the access and error log up in the question. Is there another one?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.  OK -- that clearly shows the URL is understood correctly, but is denied.  In that case.. hmm, can't format this properly in a comment, see answer down below.

Comment: I have the same problem as you, and I just do : chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/myusername  , it work's for me

Comment: There are new security defaults in macOS 12 “Monterey”. By default, other users have no access to another user's home directory. This includes the special “_www” user that is running the Apache web server. Run the following command to give the Apache web server access to the Sites folder in your home directory.

Reference : https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250004361

chmod +a "_www allow execute" ~

Answer (score 23):

[Apple has a support document for this problem](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25038). Fixing the issue involves creating a file `/etc/apache2/users/yourusername.conf` (*yourusername* being the account *short name*, e.g. `danielbeck` – it's usually the name of your home folder in `/Users`) with the following contents:

```
<Directory "/Users/yourusername/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Afterwards, run `sudo chown root:wheel /etc/apache2/users/yourusername.conf` and restart Apache.

Comment: and too restart your apache, just execute `sudo apachectl restart` in your terminal.

Answer (score 16):

For Apache to see the file, the user that Apache runs as (probably `www` or `_www`) must have access to these users' Sites directories. Having read/execute access to the contents of `~/Sites` is not enough, because it has to be allowed to traverse from `/` down the path to `~/Sites`. So make sure `/`, `/Users`, `/Users/myusername`, and `/Users/myusername/Sites` all have at least `a+x` permission (the eXecute bit on directories allows that user class to traverse the directory, even if Read access is not allowed).

```
ls -lde / /Users/ /Users/myusername/ /Users/myusername/Sites
```

If any of those directories doesn't show the last `x` set (the one for "others"), then use something like `chmod a+x ...` to set it for that directory.

If the ACL for any of those directories shows that user `www` has been specifically denied access, then use the appropriate arguments to `chmod` to fix the ACLs.

Comment: The execute bit is set for all of those directories, but I don't know how to check if a specific user has been denied access.

Comment: That's what the "e" in "ls -lde" is for. It lists the ACLs (if any) for each of the files.

Comment: Changing permissions on /Users/myusername to chmod 755 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Doesn't this command give the _www user permission to access your root directory, as well as the /Users directory, etc?  That can't possibly be right, is it?  All of those security holes to share a page in one folder?  Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Replying to my own comment, I found this answer ( http://serverfault.com/a/293063/14970 ) which does provide a link to reliable documentation on this behavior: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: For the record: Adding +x doesn't give read or write permission to anything, it just allows the user to navigate down to a directory where they do have read access (in this case, the Sites directory).

Comment: I had this issue and found a simple single file symlink worked but sym linking to a directory did not. Turned out the directories I was linking to had a sticky bit set like this `drwxr-xr-x@`. Doing a `chmod 755 dirName` to remove the sticky bit fixed the issue, as Mark R pointed out above.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, I just dealt with this, and none of the answers here worked in my specific case. I was configuring virtual hosts, but more importantly, I needed my htaccess files to actually work.

I changed on "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in my /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf file, and all of my sites started to be forbidden.

I changed it back and and then changed it only for one site in my httpd-vhosts.conf file, and only that site was forbidden.

After looking at the logs and seeing the problem was with url rewriting and the lack of FollowSymLinks, I went back to the USERNAME.conf file. I switch "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" and added "Options +FollowSymLinks" on the next line.

Things started working. I came from using xampp on windows and it had a lot of these settings already set server-wide for dummies like me.

Comment: thanks so much, spent quite some time figuring out what's going on, didn't have to tinkle with Apache / PHP for some time now

Comment: Yep, `Options +FollowSymLinks` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: My (old) account wasn't accessible, but another user's account which were created after upgrading to Lion worked just fine.

After making sure your /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf looks like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

do a 
    sudo chown root:wheel /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf

it appears that this permission setting isn't set during the OS upgrade, and the Apache user can't read the config file, and throws an error.

At least this solved it for me.

Comment: And maybe run `sudo apachectl restart` after that.

Comment: This working for me running 10.7.5. The Directory path wasn't pointing to my local web root, once I updated and restarted apache everything worked. What is strange is that the path has been incorrect for over a year and was working the whole time. I just got the error today out of the blue.

Answer (score 2):

update for Lion in 10/2011
I had to also add

UserDir enabled   so my 
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf is like this :

```
UserDir enabled 
UserDir Sites

#
# Users might not be in /Users/*/Sites, so use user-specific config files.
#
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf

<IfModule bonjour_module>
   RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing conversation from initial question comments -- 
Check out your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file.  On my machine, I have this:

```
# User home directories
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

I suspect yours is commented out.  I vaguely recall changing this by hand when moving from 10.5 to 10.6 and the default changed.

This is probably obvious, but you'll have to use `sudo` to edit the file because it will be owned by root.

Comment: Nope, mine looks exactly like yours.

Answer (score 1):

My case is XAMPP + Mac OS X 10.7 + Directory in Dropbox Folder ( cross-referencing my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102476/qooxdoo-xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-orig) in Stack Overflow )

403 Access Forbidden is reported by Apache, therefore, I followed the above comment to change User in the `/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` , from `User nobody` to `User my_user_name`. Restart Apache & it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have [Indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index) turned on. If you don't you will need to either create an index file (`index.html` or `index.php`) or specify the file explicitly, i.e. `http://localhost/~me/mypage.html`.

Comment: Sorry, just to double check, I should be visiting http://localhost/~myusername/index.html and have a file called index.html in my Sites folder, right? If so, then the 403 is still happening.

Comment: You shouldn't be visiting `~myusername` at all I believe. `http://localhost/` should point to `/Users/youruser/Sites/`.