# http://localhost/~admin/ gets a 403

Tags: mac, apache-http-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [403 Forbidden Error on Mac OS X Localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/158792/403-forbidden-error-on-mac-os-x-localhost)

When I go to localhost/~admin/ or 127.0.0.1/~admin/ my browser says:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~admin/ on this server."

***How do I change this?!??!?! It's driving me nuts!***

when I go to localhost or 127.0.0.1/ my browser says: "It Works!".

***I'm running mac osx 10.8.***

**I created aliases in my .bash_profile file so that I can start, restart and stop Apache quickly:**

```
alias startApache="sudo apachectl start"
alias stopApache="sudo apachectl stop"
alias restartApache="sudo apachectl restart"
```

**In my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file I turned on php5:**

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

**I also made sure to change the permissions for my admin.conf file with this command in terminal:**

```
sudo chmod 644 username.conf
```

**This is my /etc/apache2/users/admin.conf:**

```
<Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does "~admin" exist?  Does the user Apache is running as have permissions to it?

Comment: @techie007 admin exists. How do I check "the user Apache is running as have permissions to it?"

Comment: Check [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/158826/23133) out.

Comment: Thanks. I went through that page. It's for 10.6. Didn't help.

Comment: Just because he's using OSX 10.6 doesn't mean the answers provided don't apply.  Did you look at Spiff's answer?  From all the info there, what did you actually try?  What were your results?

Comment: Yeah I tried Spiff's answer:

new-host:users admin$ ls -lde / /Users/ /Users/admin/ /Users/admin/Sites
drwxrwxr-x  32 root   wheel  1156 Dec  7 13:13 /
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   admin   170 Nov 20 09:39 /Users/
drwxr-xr-x+ 32 admin  staff  1088 Dec  7 16:39 /Users/admin/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   5 admin  staff   170 Dec  7 17:41 /Users/admin/Sites

They all had x's I think right? I'm so lost.

Answer (score 1):

This could be as simple as the directory listing option being turned off and there being no (configured) index file (index.html, etc)

1) Try changing the Options line to:

```
Options +Indexes MultiViews
```

If a parent directory (or the main apache.conf) has -Indexes (turned off) then without the "+" it won't force it on for the current directory.

2) You could just create a .htaccess file in the desired directory and add the one line:

```
Options +Indexes
```

3) Set the index file in admin.conf or .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php,index.html,index.htm
```

4) Make sure the Apache user at least has read access to the index file. You can do this by checking the permissions. This can be done by pressing Control+I (or Get Info) and making sure Everybody has Read permissions.

These things are good to check if you're having the same problem under Linux with Apache, too.